# Exporting Satellite Imagery from ArcGIS Desktop for Global Mapper?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, landsat, global-mapper

I have satelite imagery in ArcGIS and I want to open it in Global Mapper.
The problem is that the after exporting the image it looks like the color of the image is changing.

Here, below I have the image that I want to export from ArcGIS :
[image]

Here is the way that I export the file :
1.Right click on the layer and export data.

Here,below is the same file after i opened it in Global Mapper :
[image]

So, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I am not familiar with Global Mapper, but it might have something to do with the histogram equalising. ArcMap may automatically apply a histogram stretch.

Comment: Which format of image you use? *.tif; *.jpg

Comment: @nagib i used .tif

Comment: @keagaAllan okeh thx